# Is there a way for two AIR apps to share data?

Tags: flash, air

I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid writing a file to the file system with info that I need to pass from one installed Desktop AIR app to another.  Is there a way to do this through the `SharedObject` and if not, is there any other solution?

Comment: I dont think you can use a 'shared' SharedObject (not without using file system anyway). You could use a P2P connection; googling should provide some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seek the [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class.

If you go to that link and scroll down a bit, you'll see a paragraph that begins, "From an AIR application to another AIR application." This section of the page contains instructions and sample code. This approach works only with desktop AIR apps, not mobile apps.

Comment: This is extremely useful in that it allows two apps to talk to one another, however, in my case (and I should have made this clearer in my question) I have no reasonable expectation that the two apps will be running at the same time (though they might be).  What I need is a way for one to store a message for the other to pick up (and vice versa) whenever they happen to need to, which is why I turned to SharedObject as my first choice.  It looks like I'm going to just have to write a file to the file system and have them both look at it. Ugly, but I suspect there's no other alternative.